# How to create an overlay subnet for KVM guests on multiple hosts on OpenNebula?

Tags: networking, linux-kvm

How do I setup an overlay network spanning 2 physical hosts?

Here is my network infrastracture in question.

[image]

I'd like to be able to provision multiple VM's via OpenNebula and setup a different subnet for those guests. From my understanding I should use OpenVSwitch to create bridges with physical interfaces on the physical hosts, but that only makes the VM's appear in the original network. Is it even possible to virtualize a whole network?

From my research I believe I need to setup VXLAN for the VM's?

What I would like to do:

- Main subnet 192.168.70.0/24 - physical hosts
- VM's subnet 192.168.80.0/24 - only VM's
- Static route to 192.168.80.0/24 via one(or possibly both?) physical hosts hosting the VM's.

Both hosts are running Ubuntu 18.04.06 and OpenNebula 6.4.
Currently I have my VM's use the bridge and use the main subnet.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think the "canonical" way is to run a Nebula client on every VM.

Comment: So no way of creating a proper cluster of hosts? Is there any other software that would satisfy my needs?

Comment: It may still be possible. I've never seriously tried Nebula. I suggest you examine the documentation in detail. Other overlay networks exist, of course. However, asking for product recommendations is off-topic on Super User.